# Missing Rep and Edit Privilege -- Lost & Not Found

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Yesterday I crossed the 2,000 rep point and was notified that I have therefore earned the privilege of editing posts without the need for peer review.

Now I find the rep is 1,893 after having earned a few more points overnight. I don't remember exactly how much was the rep before the negative was applied.

I cannot find (don't know where to look/ how to) any record of negative rep applied to my account overnight. Clearly, I have lost at least 180 [2000+73(earned yesterday)-1893] and probably 200 rep overnight.

Anything I am required to do to remedy/ reverse the losses? Any insights?

Comment: Tx @Jasper Loy, entirely likely a recalc was done. How would I know, and when it was done? The rep at bottom tallies with 1893 and then the last thing at the bottom is 'Trigger a recalc' button. Does that suggest recalc was NOT done yet? Or it will the button appear anyway?

Comment: @JasperLoy Are there lists of deleted questions?  Also, such a big change being caused by deleted questions would be odd because questions with high-scoring answers seem (to me) to be less likely to be closed/deleted.

Comment: I heard the other day that sometimes there are deletions *en masse*, changing the privileges drastically. However, none of my answers is high-scoring, I am sure.

Comment: But there is no provision for the system to trigger a notification when a recalc is done/ when your privilege is canceled/ ... ? We could know the point of time when things happened, at least.

Comment: I think one way to check if a recalc was done would be to trigger a recalc now. If it reflects any downward change, then NO recalc was recently done.

Comment: Tx @JasperLoy. Done that. No change in rep 1893, recalc processed with no errors, button no longer appears. Therefore: recalc was most likely done some 25 hours earlier?

Comment: Triggering a recalc doesn't change the number you see in the /reputation page; it just syncs up your reputation shown on the site to match that number

Comment: @simchona: But here it shows that recalc **was** done, and done some 24+ hours earlier, right? 1893 is the figure shown *everywhere* today.

Answer (score 3):

That was me, as fellow mods can verify by looking at your user history. I have been running rep recalcs [for a couple weeks now](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2660902#2660902), starting with the top users and (veeery) slowly working my way down the user list, as part of the [Winter Cleaning](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2256/winter-cleaning) effort.

As others have pointed out already, you can always keep your displayed reputation in sync with your actual reputation by going to your personal rep report at [/reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/reputation), scrolling to the very bottom and clicking the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button there. Then you won't be caught off guard the next time a rep recalc is triggered for your account by a mod or a globally running script.

Answer (score 0):

The link that JasperLoy gave,
[english.stackexchange.com/reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/reputation), gives you a list of your reputation point changes, along with question numbers and item types 1,2,3... and day-totals.  (I don't know how far it goes back -- maybe a year?)  If you save that in a file you can grep for negative entries to see if they account for the drop.  For example, if you save data in rep2011.12, do:

```
grep '(-' rep2011.12
```

I don't know how deleted questions are handled but doubt  the reputation dump will show them.  For example, after

```
egrep -v ' [123]|-- 201' rep2011.12
```

(which weeds out types 1,2,3 and daily totals) I see 
only various summary lines plus network bonus line and
`8     41469 (-50)` for a bounty, respectively.

You might install the "[Reputation graph](https://stackapps.com/questions/2202/reputation-graph)" application to help find any big ups or downs rapidly.

Comment: Somehow beats me. Considering I have been on englishSE for hardly 50 days now and not very active at that, the listing is short enough for manual analysis (323 lines), even a quick overall glance all at a time almost. So where to look and what to look for? If a few (10)s have been yanked off different dates, how would it change the pattern?

Comment: The reputation page goes back to the day you created the account, as far as I know.

Comment: @Kris If deleted questions result in corresponding lines in the reputation list being deleted, a few deleted 10's are unlikely to be detectable.  If instead some reversing transactions are added, they would show up as "sawteeth" in the cumulative graph.  Seeing no such reversals in my own list, I imagine the former approach is used.